# Is it possible to change Intellij's naming convention for unit tests?

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm working on a project where the convention is to name test classes *TestSomething* insteadof *SomethingTest*. Is it possible to configure Intellij to understand this convention? It would be really nice to be able to jump between test and implementation using Ctrl+Shift-T again!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jump should work fine with any convention, IDEA is using `.*class_name.*` pattern for this feature.

Comment: Now I feel stupid! I just tried it again to prove you wrong, but it worked. Wonder what I did wrong earlier. Thanks anyway!

Comment: But is it possible to change the default name for new tests? Currently the default is SomethingTest, and like the OP I'd like it to be the reverse (maybe we work at the same place ;) ).